# StarRC extraction types vs process corners from foundry

Tags: layout

When extract layout with extraction tools such as StarRC..., we have types of extraction such as RC, C types. From foundary such as TSMC, Samsung, they provide us with corners such as RCbest, RCworst, Cbest, Cmin...
My question is that what are the differences between them? If i choose to extract with C types (Cap only, isn't it), i still have corners like RCbest, RCworst (how resistance makes sense if i extract only Cap )for simulation. I am not clear about these two differences.
Please help me explain!

Answer (score 1):

Corner simulation is usually done for dedicated devices like resistors and capacitors that are used in the design. Both types of devices usually have quite a large variation on the order +/- 20% and therefore corner simulation gives valuable information.

Parasitic extraction results in additional (parasitic) devices because interconnect has both resistance and capacitance. These parasitics are neither very accurate nor well controlled. Therefore the design should be such, that it does not degrade too much in the presence of parasitics.

I'm not sure if the corner models you have actually cover the variation of the parasitics as well. Anyway, just because you chose a certain corner (like RCbest) does not require you to actually have these components in your design. It just means that the simulation models are included.

Comment: So, what actually happens when i choose extraction type to be RC or C only in tools such as StarRC. Thanks